# Python Neo4j retrieve count in a single query for multiple match queries

Tags: python-2.7, neo4j

I am trying to get the number of links a user has, using the query shown below with neo4j-driver for python.

```
with driver.session() as session:
    query = 'MATCH (n:User {userId: "1234"})-[r]-()  RETURN COUNT(r)'
    result = session.run(query)
```

Problem is, this takes a lot of time since I have a lot of user ids. I am a noobie with Neo4j. I was just wondering if there was a way to retrieve the count for multiple user ids with a single query. I am looking for something like:

```
'MATCH (n:User {userId: "1234", "1235", "1236", ...})-\
[r1, r2, r3...]-()  RETURN COUNT(r1), COUNT(r2), COUNT(r3)...'
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may want to doublecheck that you have an index or a unique constraint (whichever makes the most sense) on :User(userId) to ensure the match to that particular node is fast. Use an EXPLAIN or PROFILE of the query to view the query plan. You want to see a NodeIndexSeek or NodeUniqueIndexSeek in the plan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that you want count of relation ship of all users

```
MATCH (n:User)-[r]-()  RETURN DISTINCT n.userId ,COUNT(r)
```

- user1,10
- user2,11
- user3,10

---

or if you have list of particular users then you can do by this

```
MATCH (n:User)-[r]-()
WHERE n.userId in ["1234", "1235", "1236"]
RETURN DISTINCT n.userId , COUNT(r)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the degree of relationships from a node without paying the cost of actually expanding the relationships. This is done by getting the size of the pattern that includes only the starting node, the relationship type, and the relationship direction (though for this example, ignoring direction).

So in this case:

```
MATCH (n:User)
WHERE n.userId in ["1234", "1235", "1236"]
RETURN n.userId , size((n)-[r]-()) as degree
```